# Is it okay to exit a loop when an exception is thrown?

Tags: c#, arrays

I solved a task on Hackerrank.com, where the problem was like this:

> You have an Array. This Array contains numbers.
>   Now you enter two numbers:
>
> - The first one describes a sum
> - The second one describes the amount of indexes (sequence length) you add together
>
> In the end you get the amount of sequences whose sum is your defined number
>
> For example:
>
> Your array is [ 1, 2, 3, 4], your sum is 3 and your sequence length is 2.
>   Now you take the first two indexes and output the sum: [1, 2] = 3.
>   This is equal to your sum, so now you have found one sequence.
>   The next sequence is [ 2, 3 ] = 5. This is not equal to 3, so your sequence counter stays 1.
>   The last sequence is [3, 4] = 7. This is also not equal to 3 and in the end, you found one sequence.

I wrote this code for that:

```cs
static int GetSequences(List<int> s, int d, int m)
{
    //m = segment-length
    //d = sum

    int count = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0; 

    do
    {
        try
        {
            List<int> temp = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                temp.Add(s[i + k]);
            }
            if (temp.Sum() == d)
            {
                count++;
            }
            j++;
            k++;
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            break;
        }

    } while (true);

    return count;
}
```

As I didn't know how often I have to count
(For example a 6-Length-Array with a sequence-length of 3 has 4 sequences (1,2,3 | 2,3,4 | 3,4,5 | 4,5,6)),
I am stopping the `while` loop when the index is out of range. but I'm not sure if this solution is okay. Not just with program speed, but also with code cleanliness. Is this code acceptable, or is it better to use a `for` loop, which loops for example exactly 4 times for a 6-length array with 3-Length sequences?

Comment: It is ugly. Can you check if `i + k >= s.Count` instead? If it is the case, `return count;` from the inner loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not recommended, no. Exceptions should be reserved for stuff that isn't supposed to happen, not flow control or validation.

What you want is to use conditional logic (if statements) and the `break` keyword.

Also, codereview.stackexchange.com is better suited for these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to fix your code so that it doesn't routinely throw exceptions:

You sum each of these segments:

```
0  1  2  3    start = 0
|  |          summing indexes: 0, 1
+--+

0  1  2  3    start = 1
   |  |       summing indexes: 1, 2
   +--+

0  1  2  3    start = 2
      |  |    summing indexes: 2, 3
      +--+
```

The bracket starts at the index `start`, and has a size of `m`. The length of `s` is given by `s.Count`. Therefore we want to keep going until `start + m == s.Count`.

(I always find it's useful to draw these things out, and put sample numbers in, in order to make sure you've got the maths right. In the sample above, you can see that we stop when `start (2) + m (2) == the array size (4)`)

```
static int GetSequences(List<int> s, int d, int m)
{
    //m = segment-length
    //d = sum

    int count = 0;

    for (int start = 0; start + m <= s.Count; start++)
    {
        List<int> temp = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            temp.Add(s[start + i]);
        }
        if (temp.Sum() == d)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

---

However, you can improve your code a bit:

1. Use meaningful variable names
2. Don't create a new temporary list each time, just to sum it
3. Check your inputs

```
static int GetSequences(List<int> numbers, int targetSum, int segmentLength)
{
    if (numbers == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(numbers));
    if (segmentLength > numbers.Count)
        throw new ArgumentException("segmentLength must be <= numbers.Count");

    int count = 0;

    for (int start = 0; start + segmentLength <= numbers.Count; start++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < segmentLength; i++)
        {
            sum += numbers[start + i];
        }
        if (sum == targetSum)
        {
            count++;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You could even remove the inner loop. You only have to initialize sum and then keep deducting the number that falls off and add the new number and check that value.

Comment: @Knoop Absolutely right. I'm trying to take things slowly for them

Answer (score 0):

Usually except for switch/case there is often no real reason to use break.
Also an exception **MUST** be as the name says exceptional, so it **MUST NOT** be a part of your logic.
As said Jeppe you can use the methods and attributes the framework provides you to do as you like.
Here `s.Count` seems to be the way to go.

Comment: I disagree with break only being usable in switches, it can be a very good tool in a `for`/`while` loop when, for whatever reason, there's nothing to do anymore in the loop but you still need to run some logic after the loop (thus preventing the use of `return`).

Comment: Indeed, I didn't say that it was always bad, just don't see it as a go to, it can lead to some bad practices and behaviours, if it used too much for evry for/while loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] arr = new[] { 1, 2, 1, 2 };
// Sum and len are given by the task.
// 'last' is the last index where we should stop iterating.
int sum = 3, len = 2, last = arr.Length - len;
// One of the overloads of Where accepts index, i.e. the position of element.
// 1) We check that we don't go after our stop-index (last).
// 2) Avoid exception by using '&&'.
// 3) We use C# 8 Range (..) to get the slice of the numbers we need:
//    we start from the current position (index) till then index,
//    calculated as current index + length given by the task.
// 4) Sum all the numbers in the slice (Sum()) and compare it with the target sum,
//    given by the task (== sum).
// 5) The count of all matches (Count()) is the sought amount of sequences.  
int count = arr.Where((z, index) => index <= last && arr[index..(index+len)].Sum() == sum).Count();
```

Comment: @Mohammad Which link?

Comment: Code only answers are not encouraged here, can you explain the context how this answer will help..

Comment: @ArunVinoth Added explanation